# Count of Collection property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a count of a collection property within using linq. What I've tried produced this error.
`{"The specified type member 'Partners' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."}`

```
var Collection = new ObservableCollection<Projects>
                     (from item in ctx.Projects
                      select new Project
                      {
                          ProjectName = item.ProjectName,
                          Partners = item.Partners.Count()
                      })
```

I've also tried
    `Partners = item.Partners.Select(x => x.Id).Count()`
and it produces the same error

Comment: please post the `Project` entity class code

Comment: `from item in ctx.Projects.AsEnumerable()` since you are already selecting everything

Comment: Is `Project` mapped in EF?

Comment: How is `Projects.Partners` defined. If EF knows about the mapping it should be able to do that directly, rather than having the great waste of using `AsEnumerable()`.